# Как вставить ссылку на литературу внутри \caption{}

Tags: latex

Подскажите, как вставить ссылку на литературу в caption рисунка. Вот, что я хочу сделать:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\center{\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{hotspot.png}}
\caption{\link{hotspot} Имитация процесса попадания фотона на полоску сверхпроводника.}
\label{image1}
\end{figure}
```

Однако latex ругается на \link{hotspot} внутри caption. Есть ли возможность туда затолкать ссылку? Если есть, то как?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно было вставить не `link`, а `cite`.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Точно, спасибо! Извинения подвинули меня принять столь опрометчивое решение.